# jQuery UI scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery UI dialog, which on minimizing goes to a container to the left. How can I add a jQuery UI scrollbar to that container?

I tried with this, but it gives me the default dull scrollbar:

```
#dialog_window_minimized_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    size: 10px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

How do I change it to jQuery custom UI?

On maximizing, the dialog should automatically adjust to the window so that it doesn't cover the dialog container.

Answer (score 1):

this is a jquery custom content scroller which may helps you. it is nice and easy to use in all browsers, also mobile devices have a look at http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/